# Can not install to SSD -- sdb has 0B size

Tags: system-installation, ssd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 23.04 from a bootable flash drive onto an internal NVME SSD, however, I can not seem to be able to do anything with the SSD despite it being observable.

[lsblk -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZQL8.jpg)

I have the BIOS set to AHCI, and the correct size of the SSD is listed in the BIOS.

I can not modify the SSD via disks

https://imgur.com/1xCUGFr

and gparted will not list the SSD.

I also get pcieport power fault warnings at start up, which might be the issue?

https://i.imgur.com/NHmypSy.jpg

If so, is it the SDD or mother board or something else?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What brand/model SSD? Have you updated its firmware? And maybe even update motherboard firmware.

Comment: If there is an nvme SSD, it should be seen as `/dev/nvme0n1` or by `lsblk` simply as `nvme0n1` and its partitions as `nvme0n1p1` ... - `sdb` is removable and it is not an internally connected nvme drive.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was that the SSD was dead.  Replacement solved the issue.  The power fault warnings were not related.